# forcing type variable names in haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I have a phantom type

```
newtype Modulus s a = Modulus a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And an applier forcing polymorphism

```
withModulus ∷ a → (∀ s. Modulus s a → w ) → w
withModulus a k = k (Modulus a)
```

in which I make use of the type variable `s` introduced, in other types,  forcing them to share the index `s`

```
newtype M s a = M a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Plus some primitives, *at the same type index* for both types `Modulus` and `M`

```
add :: Integral a ⇒ Modulus s a → M s a → M s a → M s a
add (Modulus m) (M a) (M b) = M (mod (a + b) m)
mul :: Integral a ⇒ Modulus s a → M s a → M s a → M s a
mul (Modulus m) (M a) (M b) = M (mod (a * b) m)
```

Now this fonction would work

```
testOK m a (b::w) = withModulus m
                    (\m → let a' = (M a :: ∀ sa. M sa w) ; b' = M b -- free indexes introduced
                          in unM $ add m (mul m a' a') (mul m b' b'))
```

whereas if some type variable have to escape their scope to unify, it fails

```
testKO m (M -> a)  -- sa introduced
         (b') = withModulus m
                (\(m :: Modulus sm w) -- sm introduced
                  → let b = M b' in unM $ add m (mul m a a) (mul m b b))
```

(to unify sa == sm, `sm` would have to escape its scope)

```
• Couldn't match type ‘s0’ with ‘s’
    because type variable ‘s’ would escape its scope
  This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
    a type expected by the context:
      Modulus s w -> w
    at /Users/nrolland/Sync/clones/haskGist80/.stack-work/intero/intero88093-Bi.hs:(37,17)-(39,72)
  Expected type: M s w
    Actual type: M s0 w
```

The error message reports this error using the name `s` from the definition, not the name `sm` supplied.  It might be minor here but I imagine it can get hard to read in more complicated context.

Is there a way to force the names used ?

complete code :

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}


module Configuration where
--http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/tr-15-04.pdf

newtype Modulus s a = Modulus a deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype M s a = M a deriving (Eq, Show)
add :: Integral a ⇒ Modulus s a → M s a → M s a → M s a
add (Modulus m) (M a) (M b) = M (mod (a + b) m)
mul :: Integral a ⇒ Modulus s a → M s a → M s a → M s a
mul (Modulus m) (M a) (M b) = M (mod (a * b) m)

unM (M a) = a

data AnyModulus a = ∀ s. AnyModulus (Modulus s a)
makeModulus :: a → AnyModulus a
makeModulus a = AnyModulus (Modulus a)

withModulus ∷ a → (∀ s. Modulus s a → w ) → w
withModulus a k = k (Modulus a)

Integral w => w -> w -> w -> w
testOK m a (b::w) = withModulus m
                    (\m → let a' = (M a :: ∀ sa. M sa w) ; b' = M b -- free indexes introduced
                          in unM $ add m (mul m a' a') (mul m b' b'))


Integral w => w -> w -> w -> w
testKO m (M -> a)  -- sa introduced
         (b') = withModulus m
                (\(m :: Modulus sm w) -- sm introduced
                  → let b = M b' in unM $ add m (mul m a a) (mul m b b))
```

Comment: Why don't you add type signatures to `testOK` and `testKO`?

Comment: not sure how that would help, at this level every internal type variable is gone : the type is just  `Integral w => w -> w -> w -> w`

Comment: First of all it would _help us to understand_ what you're doing.

Comment: I see. but that's why I sprinkled the code with type signatures where it matters.  it's a standard exemple from 2009 by oleg, called implicit configurations. nothing fancy but it does uses polymorphism and type variables to existentially quantify at type level

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is close to what you are looking for.

```
testKO :: forall w. Integral w => w -> w -> w -> w
testKO m a' b' = let
   a :: forall s. M s w
   a = M a'
   in withModulus m  (\ m' → let
      b = M b'
      in unM $ add m' (mul m' a a) (mul m' b b))
```

The issue is:

- `a` will not get a polytype unless we ask for it explicitly
- we need `a` to have a polytype, or `withModulus` will not be able to choose `s` to its linking
- view patterns like `(M -> a)` do not allow, AFAICS, to specify a type annotation